# disable SSL certification verification in axios

Tags: node.js, ssl, ssl-certificate, axios

i have a problem when call API.That display 
"Error: unable to get local issuer certificate"
After that i tried add httpsAgent below.

```
var agent = new https.Agent({
    rejectUnauthorized: false
});

instance.defaults.httpsAgent = agent
```

i run this code. but display error "Agent option must be an Agent-like object, undefined, or false."
How it can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

That's a Node v.8 known bug. You must to upgrade the Node.js version you are currently using. I would always recommend you to always update to the latest LTS version if possible.

Reference of the bug [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/11567).

Comment: I was trying for about a hour to understand what's going on in here... thanks